# Environment that ignores the content

Tags: comments

I want to define the environment `ignorethis` such that

```
\begin{ignorethis}
This will not be shown and will  not take any space
\end{ignorethis}
```

Defining command that ignores the argument is simple:

```
\newcommand{\comments}[1]{}
```

Now, how can I define `ignorethis` based on `comments`?
Something like this, but do not know how to escape insert `}` and `} properly.

```
\newenvironment{ignorethis}{\comments{}{}}
```

**P.S. I know about `comment` package but I do not want to use it as it requires `fragile` frames in the beamer.**

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\comments}[1]{}
\newenvironment{ignorethis}{\comments{}{}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \comments{This text will be for sure invisible} 
    \begin{ignorethis}
      How can I ignore this? 
    \end{ignorethis}    
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably easiest using environ. It can collect the body of an env and do stuff with it (or ignore it)

Comment: See [Hiding part of the text when certain macro is enabled](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490673/hiding-part-of-the-text-when-certain-macro-is-enabled) for example ([answer using environ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490763/73317)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous answers mentioned the `environ` package.  I can confirm it works for *safe text*.  I doubt it would work for pathological examples (catcode changes, broken definitions, unmatched braces), perhaps especially with how `beamer` also collects everything and evaluates it.  In any case, here's the MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{ignore}{}{}
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}
This is a test.
\begin{ignore}
blah blah blah.

blah blah blah.
\end{ignore}
It's over.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will also post an answer which I created based on the suggestions on using `environ` (I don't use `etoolbox` but `ifthen` package).

The solution is slightly elaborated:

- For locally changing the modes: Optional `[h]` decides whether to hide or show the ignorable parts.
- For globally hiding everything: Defining `\hideallignorables` hides all ignorable environments
- For globally showing everything: Defining `\showallignorables` shows all ignorable environments even if the have `[h]` or `\hideallignorables` is defined.

**My intention is to use the environment to ignore complex TikZPictures to decrease the compilation time.**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\hideallignorables}{Hides all ignorables; It has priority over classes}
%\newcommand{\showallignorables}{Shows all ignorables; It has priority over classes and hideallignorables}

\NewEnviron{ignorable}[1][]{% #2 is a mandatory class name; #1 can be 'h' for hiding
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\showallignorables}}
    {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\hideallignorables} \AND \NOT\equal{#1}{h}}
        {\BODY}
        {}%
    }
    {\BODY}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

NOSPACE AFTER%
\begin{ignorable}
First text
\end{ignorable}%
NOSPACE BEFORE

\begin{ignorable}
Visible if hideallignorables is not defined
\end{ignorable}

\begin{ignorable}[h]
This is hidden unless showallignorables is defined 
\end{ignorable}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```