# Comment out different and disconnected part of codes without doing it manually

Tags: comments

I have a long draft I am working on. In the draft, there are comments which are not meant to be public, but that I add in order to guide my work. Sometimes, I need to share my draft (e.g. with my advisor, send it to conferences, etc.) and I have to manually comment out the comment blocks in the draft.

I wonder if there is a way to create some "comment environment" that I can decide to compile or not with one line at the beginning of the document.

Comment: You should be able to use the `maybePrint` environment from [hiding-part-of-the-text-when-certain-macro-is-enabled](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490673/). Use `\toggletrue{doPrintStuff}` when you want the contents to appear and `\togglefalse{doPrintStuff}` when you don't.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works.