# Problem with Standalone package with if statements in subfile preamble

Tags: standalone

I'm trying to use the standalone package. The idea is to have a large collection of standalone TeX files each containing a 'problem' (all text), and to be able to compile larger documents, each containing several problems selected from the pool. Now, I also want to toggle the visibility of the 'solution' to each problem, both in the main file and subfiles. I accomplish this by using `if` conditional and the comment package. But the main file fails to compile. A minimal example is as follows:

Subfile:

```
%!TeX root = sub.tex

\documentclass[class=article,crop=false,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{comment}

\newif\ifsolution

\solutiontrue

\ifsolution
\newenvironment{solution}{\medskip\textbf{Solution: }\ignorespaces}{}
\else
\excludecomment{solution}
\fi

\begin{document}
    
\subsection{Title}

Problem text.

\begin{solution}
Solution text.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}

\usepackage[subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{comment}

\newif\ifsolution

%\solutiontrue

\ifsolution
\newenvironment{solution}{\medskip\textbf{Solution: }\ignorespaces}{}
\else
\excludecomment{solution}
\fi

\title{Big Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\input{sub.tex}

\end{document}
```

Note the the preambles in both files are identical. The statement `\solutiontrue` can be (un)commented to toggle the solution.

While the subfile compiles fine, the main file does not, giving the error `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 17.` (Line 17 is just after `\title`, and the error occurs at the line containing `\input`.

The error results from the `\newif`...`\fi` block in the subfile. It can be avoided by moving this block to a separate file and `\input`ing it in the subfile. I don't want to do that because I want to be able to easily toggle the solution.

It appears that standalone can't handle this `if` in the preamble, although my understanding is that it should completely discard the subfile preamble until `\begin{document}`. Is this correct? Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Just want to add that I encountered this issue before and worked around it by putting stuff after `\begin{document}`. `standalone` when imported into a `main.tex` strips the preamble out so only between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` is actually compiled. When you compile it individually for `tikz` or whatever purpose then it includes the preamble so you may have to just have to copy and paste the same `if` blocks into your preamble and after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Won't you get a duplicate `\ifsolution` when you `\input{sub.tex}`?

Comment: @JohnKormylo No, because the sub preamble is discarded by the main file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low-level `\if` commands are rather special in TeX. Even if TeX skips over text and throws it away it sees them. So in your case when compiling main.tex TeX
sees the `\ifsolution` in the sub.tex and is rather unhappy that it has no `\fi`.

Use a boolean from etoolbox instead:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{solution}

%\booltrue{solution}

\ifbool{solution}
{\newenvironment{solution}{\medskip\textbf{Solution: }\ignorespaces}{}}
{\excludecomment{solution}}
```

Comment: Thank you. In addition I improved my preamble based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490673/hiding-part-of-the-text-when-certain-macro-is-enabled), using the `environ` package, so the boolean is evaluated within the environment.